# What do I do if I've forgotten my login credentials to aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm receiving notifications from no-reply-aws@amazon.com telling me that it can't bill my account and will shut down my account soon.

The thing is, I can't remember my login info. There is no recovery link on the login page. It just asks for "Account" (what the hell is this?), "User Name", and "Password", none of which I know.

I can't reply to the email. I can't contact support because it requires me to log in. How do I resolve this???

Comment: You looked at the [knowledge base](https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recover-AWS-password/), right?

Comment: Yup. It says to click the "Forgot password" link, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't know where you try to log in, for me the AWS login page asks for the email address to log in and provides a "forgot password" link.

Comment: I go to aws.amazon.com and click "Billing & Cost Management". Then it takes me to the login page, which doesn't have a "forgot password" link.

Comment: If you are seeing Account, username and Password then you last logged in using a subsidiary IAM account, not a root account. Log in using a different browser / incognito browser or click the link to log in using a root account.

Answer (score 5):

From the ["Recover AWS Password"](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recover-AWS-password/) page:

> You can request a password reset email by using the Forgot password? link on the [AWS sign-in page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home). An email message with further instructions will be sent to the email address currently associated with the account.
>   
>   Note: The Forgot password? link is not available on the mobile version of the AWS sign-in page. To reset your password, use the desktop version of the sign-in page instead.